# what is the possibility of all of the boys getting lower score than girls?

Tags: probability, statistics

So the question is that randomly chosen 5 boys and 5 girls' scores can be given as following:

$X(boys) = \{63,55,61,47,69\}$
$Y(girls) = \{71,74,80,88,95\}$

From above, we know the lowest 5 scores are all scored by boys. If we say that there is no difference between the score distributions for boys and girls, what is the probability of all boys getting lower scores than girls, and using that probability find out that whether the score distributions of boys and girls have no difference, given the significance level of 5%.

Here what I have tried is that I found out the average of 10 sample was 70.3,
and boys average was 59. Also found out the standard deviation is 13.96 when rounded
Hence

$\frac{59-70.3}{13.96*\sqrt{5}}$

But I found out that this is just getting the z-score of boys scoring average of 59 when girls and boys score distributios are the same, not about the probability of all boys getting lower than girls.

Can someone help me out with this question?

Comment: I don't know Statistics, so I can't answer the 2nd part.  If there are $2n$ scores, the probability that the boys have the lowest $n$ scores is $$\frac{1}{\binom{2n}{n}}.$$

Comment: This is very unlikely to have occurred by chance.  There are $10!$ ways to list the students, and $5!\times 5!$ ways to list them such that all the boys come first.  Thus the probability you want is $\frac {5!\times 5!}{10!}\approx .004$ which is well below your $5\%$ confidence level.

Comment: @lulu  Thank you!